# argument deduction failing in templated function

Tags: c++, templates

I am receiving the following error when I try to compiler the code below.
I was expecting that the function template would infer automatically the argument type for those classes but this is not happening
This code doesn't copile alsowhen  I make the types explicit.

What C++ rule I am not taking into account/missin in this process and what would be the fix?

Regards

AFG

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘wrap_call(test<ciccio>&, get_value&)


template <typename T>
struct test{    
    typedef T   value_type;
    T m_data;
};

template<typename T,typename F>
typename F::return_type wrap_call( T& obj ,F& f){
    return f.operator()(obj);
}

struct ciccio{
    int m_value;
};

struct get_value
: std::unary_function<test<ciccio>,ciccio*>
{
    ciccio* operator()(test<ciccio>& obj){
        return &obj.m_data;
    }
};

int main(){
    test<ciccio> obj;
    get_value g;
    ciccio* p = (obj,g);
    // same error if I make the types explicit
    //ciccio* p = wrap_call<test<ciccio>,get_value>(obj,g);
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
typename F::return_type
```

Should be:

```
typename F::result_type
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See, for instance, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/unary_function).

Comment: oooops!  ..thanks Andy..I spent 1 hr on it...

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile: No problem, that happens :)

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile: If this solves your problem, could you please consider accepting the answer?